# Clarification regarding Eq. (2.4.8)(2.4.9) Weinberg Vol. 1

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lorentz-symmetry

A Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$ takes a ($4$-)vector $A^{\mu}$ to $(\Lambda A)^{\mu}={\Lambda^{\mu}}_{\nu}A^{\nu}$. The unitary operator $U(\Lambda)$ corresponding to $\Lambda$ transform a state vector $\Psi$ and an operator $O$ in the Hilbert space to $U(\Lambda)\Psi$ and $U(\Lambda)OU^{-1}(\Lambda)$ respectively. Especially, it is reasonably to transform a vector operator like momentum $P^{\mu}$ to $U(\Lambda)P^{\mu}U^{-1}(\Lambda)\overset{?}{=}{\Lambda^{\mu}}_{\nu}P^{\nu}$. But in Eq. (2.4.9)  Weinberg Vol.1 the transformation actually is $U(\Lambda)P^{\mu}U^{-1}(\Lambda)={\Lambda_{\nu}}^{\mu}P^{\nu}={(\Lambda^{-1})^{\mu}}_{\nu}P^{\nu}$. It seems like that $U(\Lambda)$ is corresponding to $\Lambda^{-1}$. How to understand this result?

Comment: The convention Weinberg chooses is that the state $U(\Lambda) |p\rangle$ has momentum $\Lambda p$. This is true if $U(\Lambda)^{-1} P^\mu U(\Lambda) = \Lambda^\mu{}_\nu P^\nu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weinberg defines his group multiplication law by
$$
U(\Lambda_1) U(\Lambda_2) = U(\Lambda_1\Lambda_2)
$$
If I understand correctly, your expectation is
$$
U(\Lambda) A^\mu U(\Lambda)^{-1} = \Lambda^\mu{}_\nu A^\nu . 
$$
It is easy to see that this expectation is in fact not right. Note
\begin{align}
(\Lambda_1 \Lambda_2)^\mu{}_\nu A^\nu &= U(\Lambda_1\Lambda_2) A^\mu (\Lambda_1\Lambda_2)^{-1}  \\
&= U(\Lambda_1)U(\Lambda_2) A^\mu U(\Lambda_2)^{-1} U(\Lambda_1)^{-1} \\
&=(\Lambda_2)^\mu{}_\nu U(\Lambda_1)  A^\nu  U(\Lambda_1)^{-1} \\
&= (\Lambda_2)^\mu{}_\nu (\Lambda_1)^\nu{}_\alpha A^\alpha \\
&= ( \Lambda_2 \Lambda_1)^\mu{}_\nu A^\nu. 
\end{align}
which leads to a contradiction.

The correct formula is
$$
U(\Lambda) A^\mu U(\Lambda)^{-1} = (\Lambda^{-1})^\mu{}_\nu A^\nu
$$

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I think I found where I was wrong. The transition matrix element of vector operator should transform like a vector but not the operator itself, i.e. $\left\langle U(\Lambda)\Psi\right|P^{\mu}\left|U(\Lambda)\Phi\right\rangle={\Lambda^{\mu}}_{\nu}\left\langle \Psi\right| P^{\nu}\left|\Phi\right\rangle$ then gives  $U^{-1}(\Lambda)P^{\mu}U(\Lambda)={\Lambda^{\mu}}_{\nu}P^{\nu}$.